# ffmpeg ignores -hls_time argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get ffmpeg to convert a realtime video stream (provided via stdin) to HLS.

```sh
ffmpeg -nostdin -i pipe:0 -map i:0x66 -map i:0x67 -f hls -hls_init_time 5 -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_allow_cache 0 -vf yadif -codec libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -x264-params keyint=150 -acodec aac -b:a 128k ../output/index.m3u8
```

It mostly works, but the -hls_time argument appears to be completely ignored, as many of the generated segments are less than 3 seconds long. (In one case, a segment was just over 1 second long)

I initially ran into this issue on ffmpeg 3.4.4, (the highest version released for Ubuntu Bionic Beaver) but I've now built ffmpeg from source and I'm still having the same issue.

```bsh
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-93335-ga8c5ae4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --arch=x86_64 --cpu=znver1
libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are any segments greater than 5 seconds?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, I have seen some as long as 7 seconds. Based on my input video's framerate of 25fps and keyint=150, if hls_time is using the default value of 2s then segments could be as long as 8 seconds. If hls_time is respected, segments might be up to 11 seconds in length. So this also suggests that hls_time is still using the default value.

Comment: Change to  `-x264-params keyint=150:min-keyint=150` and check.

Comment: @Gyan I set `-hls_time 8 -x264-params keyint=100:min-keyint=100` and now my segments all seem to be between 4 and 12 seconds long. It's weird, hls_time does seem to be ignored, but if it's using the default value of 2 and I'm forcing keyframes every 4 seconds, I'd expect every segment to be 4 seconds long exactly.

Comment: It seems it's not *ignoring* `hls_time`. I set `hls_time` to 30 seconds and now my segments are roughly 22 seconds long.

Answer (score 2):

I would need to see your playlist to be 100% sure, but most likely the reason you're seeing such behaviour is because ffmpeg is trying to segment your video on keyframe boundaries. This is a common problem when preparing HLS streams with ffmpeg.

Even though you're telling ffmpeg to have a keyframe *at most* every 150 frames, ffmpeg is also inserting keyframes at scene changes (which improves video quality).

Gyan's suggestion in the comments was a valid one, since making `keyint` equal to `keyint_min` should've resulted in the video having a fixed GOP length - and as a result forcing segmentation on equal intervals. However, within libx264 the value of `keyint_min` is clamped to `keyint / 2 + 1`

```
h->param.i_keyint_min = x264_clip3( h->param.i_keyint_min, 1, h->param.i_keyint_max/2+1 );
```

Another issue is that your GOP length is 150 frames. For a video of 25 fps that's a keyframe every 6 seconds. Were it not for scene detection keyframes you would be unable to meet the segment length specified by `hls_time` for this reason alone.

From my experience, the way the `hls_time` parameter works is that it tries to keep an "average" segment length - if it's unable to segment the video at exactly `hls_time` seconds it's going to try to compensate for it resulting in segments that are both shorter and longer than the duration specified.

#### Solution

Your best bet would be to lower your GOP length, so that it can fit within the `hls_time`. Even better, make sure `hls_time` is a multiple of your GOP length (so as not to rely on scene cut keyframes).

On top of that I'd recommend fixing the keyframes by adding

`-force_key_frames "expr:if(isnan(prev_forced_n),1,eq(n,prev_forced_n+$GOP))"`

parameter to ffmpeg (where `$GOP` is a shell variable that contains the GOP length you selected).

I have described some of these issues in an article on [how to prepare media for HLS streaming](https://marcinchmiel.com/articles/2020-10/why-you-should-force-fixed-closed-gops-and-how-to-do-it-in-ffmpeg/#making-it-work-with-ffmpeg), you might want to check it out to get deeper understanding of the things needed for HLS streaming.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After I posted this question I did some digging through the ffmpeg source code and found exactly what you'd said: hls_time is treated as an average target, not a minimum.

It was a while ago, but I think the solution I went with was to set keyint to my desired minimum segment length, and hls_time to be double keyint. E.g. keyint of 5 seconds, hls_time of 10 seconds. That way, generated segments range between 5 seconds and 15 seconds in duration, but are never shorter than 5 seconds.

Comment: @JoshuaWalsh Exactly. A rule of thumb would be to set `hls_time` to a multiple of GOP length (while also fixing it, with which - judging by the variance in segment lengths - it seems you're still having some issues). I find it the videos are then segmented to what you would typically expect.

Comment: @JoshuaWalsh On the other hand, you might want to look into lowering your GOP length. Between 2 and 3 seconds is what is typically seen in HLS applications.

Comment: I don't need every segment to be exactly the same length, I just need them to never be shorter than a certain minimum length. Allowing keyframes on scene changes gives benefits to compression that I'd like to keep. I'll probably adjust it to 3 seconds with 6 second segments though.